# jQuery + A function that returns clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been stuck on this for a long time now, I am looking for a bit of guidance ... 
I want to turn the following, into something more dynamic. I want the 'selector' to change / be based on whichever element was clicked.

So this is kind of what I think needs to be done:

1. figure out which element was clicked. (h1, p, ol)
2. with that element now in a variable, apply a similar function to the one i've created below..

Otherwise, I have to specify this same function for every element instance. (h1, h2, h3, p, ul, ol)

So far this is what I have: (which works, but evidently only for my h1 element)

```
$("#content_body h1").click(function() {    
        $(this).hide(); //hide current element.
        $(this).next().show(); //display next element.

        var numofEl = $("#content_body h1").length;

        if ($(this).next().index() == numofEl) { //if we're at last element,
        $("h1:first-child").show(); //restart cycle.
        }
});
```

Any help is always very much appreciated.. Thanks in advance!

****Update*****

Another way of putting this / describe what I'm trying to get at:

Say you have many different elements in a container. (eg > #content_body)

- for each different element type (h1, h2, p) - only display one at a time. (starting by default with first of each el.)
- when you click the element, it cycles through that same element sibling. (h1 will hide current h1, and display next h1, when it reaches end / last h1, it restarts cycle)

Comment: Do you want to apply the *same* function to all elements or a *similar* function? When you say `$(this).next()` do you want the next element of the same type or *any next element*

Comment: Hi Nivas, when I am saying next, I mean the next same element, so if we're talking h1 element, it will go to next h1 sibling.

Answer (score 1):

You can comma separate your selector if you want to apply it to several different DOM elements:

```
$('h1,p,ol').click(function(){ })
```

Comment: hmmm, but that doesn't solve my problem of keeping the 'cycling' specific to the element that was clicked. If I click on h1 element, I want it to hide the current one, display the next, until it reaches last h1 and then repeat.

Comment: Are these elements nested? Or just contiguous?

Comment: They're contiguous. They all sit in a surrounding #content_body div.

Comment: What you could do, if you can, is assign ID's to each that are numbers and you could do $('selector'+id).click()

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [**jquery multiple selectors**](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

you can do it a couple of ways like

```
$("h1,p,ol,div").bind("click",function(){

//write the generic code here
});
```

also (as suggested by `8vius`)

```
$('h1,p,ol,div').click(function(){ 
//write the generic code here
})
```

inside the handler you can access the clicked element by `$(this)` or `this`

**here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6gCRF/**

Answer (score 0):

You can make the function dynamic like this:

```
showHide('h1');
showHide('p');
showHide('ol');

function showHide(element){

    $(element).click(function() {    
            $(element).hide(); //hide current element.
            $(element).next().show(); //display next element.

            var numofEl = $(element).length;

            if ($(element).next().index() == numofEl) { //if we're at last element,
            $(element).eq(0).show(); //restart cycle.
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
var length = $("#content_body").children().length;
$("#content_body").children().each(function(index){

$(this).click(function() {    
$(this).hide(); //hide current element.
$(this).next().show(); //display next element.


if (length-1 == index) { //if we're at last element,
$("h1:first-child").show(); //restart cycle.
}
});
 });
```

Comment: hmmm, somewhat. I need it to be specific to the current elements siblings only. eg > If I click the h1, cycle through only h1 elements. When it reaches last h1 in container, restart cycle.